# how to configure visual studio 2022 C++ project to redirect Dlls

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I currently have an application under visual studio 2022, which uses the openworld_470.dll library
the app is working properly.

I would now like in the application to create a libs directory containing the openworld_470.dll libraries

the application no longer works when I move the libraries from the root of the application to the libs directory.

Do you have an idea to solve this linkage problem which seems simple at the base?

I added in the project configuration in the VC++ directories -> references directory $(CommonExecutablePath)\libs;
it still does not work.

By adding in the system PATH the path of my application/libs the app works but I don't have to modify the PATH.

Comment: That's a bad idea.  Rules are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order).

Comment: I presume you are currently using load-time linking to try to load your dll. However if you changed to use run-time linking you can use `SetDllDirectory` to set the dll search path to `libs` directory and then use `LoadLibrary` to load the dll.

Comment: thank, I think I'll go with static libraries

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use `SetDllDirectory` to add the `libs` directory to your search path.

And then to set the loading of `openworld_470.dll` to be delayed. You can do this by adding `/DELAYLOAD:openworld_470.dll` to your linker settings.